# Getting error when running the app android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am developing a quiz app when i run this app i am getting error android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 after changing the minimum sdk from 16 to 19.Please help me run this app

Here is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.awwalsoft.javaplay.MainActivity">




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view1"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:onClick="startGame"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
                        android:src="@drawable/play"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/start"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twozerotext"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view1_1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/scoreboard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/highscore"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textsizebutton"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/highscore"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twozerotext"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/useapps"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sptextsize2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">


            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">



            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/minhigh"
                android:onClick="javaBasicsLearningApp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/cardviewmarginright"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
                        android:src="@drawable/jbl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/jbl"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twozerotext"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view2_1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/minhigh"
                android:onClick="javaDeepLearningApp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
                        android:src="@drawable/jdl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/jdl"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twozerotext"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view2_2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/minhigh"
                android:onClick="learnJdbcApp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
                        android:src="@drawable/jdbc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/ljdbc"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twozerotext"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>


            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>










        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view3"
                android:onClick="helpClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eightdpmargin"
                        android:src="@drawable/help"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sixteendppadding"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/help"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/helptext"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textsizemain"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.awwalsoft.javaplay;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String moreApps1 = "com.awwalsoft.javabasicslearning";
    String moreApps2 = "com.awwalsoft.javadeeplearning";
    String moreApps3 = "com.awwalsoft.learnjdbc";
    private Player currentPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        currentPlayer = ((JavaPlay) getApplication()).player; //gets player from lightquiz application
        updateHighScore();


    }

    public void javaBasicsLearningApp(View v){


        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + moreApps1)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + moreApps1)));
        }


    }

    public void javaDeepLearningApp(View v){

        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + moreApps2)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + moreApps2)));
        }


    }

    public void learnJdbcApp(View v){

        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + moreApps3)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + moreApps3)));
        }


    }

    public void helpClick(View view){
        Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this,Help.class);
        startActivity(helpIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).clearQuestions();
        updateHighScore();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
    }

    public void startGame(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayGame.class);
                startActivity(intent);


    }

    void selecGenre() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
        String[] genres = QuestionGenre.names();
        builder.setItems(QuestionGenre.names(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                beginQuizGame(QuestionGenre.names()[which]);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    void beginQuizGame(String genre) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayGame.class);
        intent.putExtra("Genre", genre);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void updateHighScore() {
        TextView highScoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
        highScoreText.setText(currentPlayer.getHighScore());
    }

}
```

here is my PlayGame.java file

```
package com.awwalsoft.javaplay;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PlayGame extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int questionsDelay = 500;
    private final int questionsPoints = 10;
    private final int questionSeconds = 8;
    private int points;
    private int lives;
    private int correctAnswer;
    //Layout Stuff
    private ImageView correctImg;
    private ImageView wrongImg;
    private ImageView questionImg;
    private TextView questionText;
    private Button soundButton;
    private TextView pointsText;
    private TextView lifeText;
    private TextView countdownText;
    private Button[] answerButtons = new Button[4];

    private CountDownTimer countdown;
    private QuestionsGenerator generator;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    private String genreSelection = null;
    private boolean gameFinished = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        genreSelection = intent.getStringExtra("Genre");


        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading Database ");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.show();



        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadQuestions();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                loadLayout();


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startGame();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        countdown.cancel();
        hideQuestionMultimedia();
        this.finish();
        gameFinished = true;
        // gameOver();

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // this.finish();
        gameOver();
    }

    //an answer was clicked
    public void answerClicked(View view) {
        countdown.cancel();
        int answer; //-1 by default
        buttonsActive(false);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.answer_1:
                answer = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.answer_2:
                answer = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.answer_3:
                answer = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.answer_4:
                answer = 4;
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown button ID");
        }
        if (correctAnswer == answer) correctAnswer();
        else wrongAnswer();
        updateTexts();
        nextQuestion();
    }

    public void soundClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.sound_button:
                playSound();
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown button ID");

        }
    }

    //set a new question from generator

    private void playSound() {
        if (!gameFinished)
            ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).soundHandler.playQuestionSound();
    }

    private void setQuestion() {
        if (!gameFinished) {
            hideQuestionMultimedia();
            buttonsActive(true);
            Question quest = generator.getQuestion();//get a randomized question

            if (!quest.isValid()) throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Question");
            this.correctAnswer = quest.getCorrectAnswer();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                answerButtons[i].setText(quest.getAnswer(i)); //set questions layout

            hideAnswerImage();
            questionText.setText(quest.getText());
            QuestionType qt = quest.type();
            switch (qt) {
                case TEXT:
                    //showQuestionText(((TextQuestion) quest).text);
                    break;
                case IMAGE:
                    showQuestionImage(((ImageQuestion) quest).image);
                    break;
                case SOUND:
                    showQuestionSound(((SoundQuestion) quest).sound);
                    playSound();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid question type");
            }
            countdown = new CountDownTimer(questionSeconds * 1000, 500) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    countdownText.setText(Integer.toString((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + 1));
            /* if(millisUntilFinished/1000 == 1) {
                 wrongAnswer();
                 updateTexts();
                 nextQuestion();
             }*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    buttonsActive(false);
                    wrongAnswer();
                    updateTexts();
                    nextQuestion();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

    private void showQuestionSound(String sound) {
        soundButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        soundButton.setClickable(true);
        ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).soundHandler.setQuestionSound(sound);
    }

    private void showQuestionImage(String imagename) {
        int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        questionImg.setImageResource(resourceId);
        questionImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //questionImg.setMaxHeight();
    }

    private void hideQuestionMultimedia() {
        questionImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        soundButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).soundHandler.stopQuestionSound();
        soundButton.setClickable(false);
    }
    //next question after som time
    private void nextQuestion() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (generator.size() == 0) gameOver(); //no more questions left
                else setQuestion();
            }
        }, questionsDelay);
    }

    //What happens when a correct answer was clicked
    private void correctAnswer() {
        points += questionsPoints;
        wrongImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        correctImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).soundHandler.playCorrectSound();
    }

    //What happens when a wrong answer was clicked
    private void wrongAnswer() {
        correctImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wrongImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).soundHandler.playWrongSound();
        lives--;
        if (lives == 0) gameOver();
    }

    //Hides any answer image (tick or cross)
    private void hideAnswerImage() {
        correctImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        wrongImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void buttonsActive(boolean b) {
        for (Button button : answerButtons) {
            button.setClickable(b);
        }
    }

    private void loadLayout() {
        correctImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.correct_img);
        wrongImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong_img);
        pointsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points_text);
        lifeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.life_text);
        countdownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown_text);
        questionImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.question_image);
        questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        soundButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound_button);

        answerButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_1);
        answerButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_2);
        answerButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_3);
        answerButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_4);

        hideAnswerImage();
    }

    //Updates life and score texts
    private void updateTexts() {
        lifeText.setText("Life:" + lives);
        pointsText.setText("Score:" + points);
        countdownText.setText("");
    }

    private void gameOver() {
        //hideQuestionMultimedia();
        gameFinished = true;
        ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).soundHandler.stopQuestionSound();
        soundButton.setClickable(false);
        countdown.cancel();
        buttonsActive(false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
        intent.putExtra("Score", points);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

    //reloads questions from xml (old)
   /* private void reload_questions() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        XmlResourceParser xmlq = getResources().getXml(R.xml.questions);
        MainActivity.generator.loadQuestions(xmlq);
        xmlq.close();
    }*/

    //Starts game
    private void startGame() {
        points = 0;
        lives = 3;
        gameFinished = false;
        buttonsActive(true);
        updateTexts();
        setQuestion();
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Quiz is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        View fore = findViewById(R.id.foreground);
        fore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    private void loadQuestions() throws IOException {
        if (!Question.isQuestionListReady()) {
            ((JavaPlay) this.getApplicationContext()).loadRawQuestions(genreSelection);
        }
        this.generator = new QuestionsGenerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `currentPlayer.getHighScore()` return?

Comment: it's return the high score of the game to the user

Comment: What type does `currentPlayer.getHighScore()` return? An `int`?

Comment: yes the currentPlayer.getHighScore() return an int value

Comment: You need to convert it to a `String` first. Changing your `minSdkVersion` wasn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: ok after changing it to a String i am getting an error again  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.awwalsoft.javaplay.QuestionType.ordinal()' on a null object reference

Comment: I would guess that `quest.type()` is returning null.

Comment: here is the code for QuestionType                                                       public enum QuestionType {
    TEXT, SOUND, IMAGE;

    public static QuestionType getRandomType() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int selec = rand.nextInt(QuestionType.values().length);
        return QuestionType.values()[selec];
    }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is somewhere you are setting text as int. like in below line

> highScoreText.setText(currentPlayer.getHighScore());

if getHighScore() return int then os will look for resource in string.xml which will give you **.Resources$NotFoundException**. Try to use it like below.

```
highScoreText.setText(String.valueOf(currentPlayer.getHighScore()));
```

Or

```
highScoreText.setText(currentPlayer.getHighScore()+"");
```

Comment: after setting this i am getting a new error

Comment: What new error . i have just gave you an example . If you have a integer value then you need to convert it to String before setting to TextView .

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.awwalsoft.javaplay.QuestionType.ordinal()' on a null object reference

Comment: Well Thats a NullPointerException. Your code need debugging .Find out the line number and Check why this happening . Check for null then do the stuff .

Comment: here is my QuestionType                                                         
       public enum QuestionType {
    TEXT, SOUND, IMAGE;

    public static QuestionType getRandomType() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int selec = rand.nextInt(QuestionType.values().length);
        return QuestionType.values()[selec];
    }

}

Comment: Edit your question with code . Do not put in comment .